# Locals/ Helpers Provided By Passport

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

I finally got done replacing an `everyauth`/ `mongoose-auth` login system with a `passport` implementation.  I'm using this purely for local username/ password logins, so I'm also utilizing the `passport-local` module as well.

I know from looking through a few examples, I found Passport auto-assigns a couple `req` helpers.  I've not been able to find a full list of variables it puts there though, a couple I've found are `req.isAuthenticated()` and the `req.user` variables.

Is there a full list provided anywhere online?  Just interested in my options available in routes/ views.  I can keep trolling through examples, but it would be nice if there was a reference somwhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a Connect/Express application,

1.`var passport = require('passport');`

The following four helper functions are added to `http.IncomingMessage.prototype`(i.e., the request object's prototype):

- login/logIn(user, [options,] done)
- logout/logOut()
- isAuthenticated() - i.e. whether `req.user` exists.
- isUnauthenticated()

If a user is authenticated successfully, usually a callback function `done(null, user)` is called. This callback function then calls `req.logIn()` which in turn calls `serializeUser()` to store the user id as `req._passport.session.user`.

The `req.logOut()` function deletes `req._passport.session.user`.

2.`app.use(passport.initialize());`

Get the passport info from current session and store it as `req._passport.session`(i.e., `req.session['passport']`).

3.`app.use(passport.session());`

Check whether `req._passport.session.user` exists, that is, whether the user id is stored in current session. If yes, call `deserializeUser()` to get the user object which will be stored as `req.user`.

Comment: Thanks for the tips on integrating passport, but I've actually already completed these steps.  What I'm interested in is what `req` or `app.local` variables passport/ passport-local exposes to the application.

Comment: I don't mean to give a step by step guide to integrate passport. I explain the functions and variables passport exposes in each step.

Comment: Ok thanks, I see what you mean now.  Thanks for the informative post, now it definitely answers what I was looking for.